# Script on router with DD-WRT can't be executed because it isn't found

Tags: networking, router, script, dd-wrt

I have a netgear nighhawk r7000 router with the DD-WRT "Kong Mod" release: 04-19-2016. I was trying to block ads directly on the router with pixelserv following [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/51477/how-to-remove-advertisements-with-pixelserv-on-dd-wrt/) tutorial  (and yes I have set the script to be executable).

Unfortunately it doesn't work.

It is written in the tutorial that saving the command for startup like this `/jffs/dns/disable_adds.sh` should result in the script beeing run at startup.

When trying to start the script directly like written above via the command shell of the webinterface of the router I get the following message:

```
sh: eval: line 1: /jffs/dns/disable_adds.sh: not found
```

Trying an `echo $PWD` in the mentioned command shell returns `/www` which is a folder parallel in the hierarchy to `/jffs`.

Using `ls ../jffs/dns` in the same shell does show that the script is found where it is supposed to be. Trying to run the script with `../jffs/dns/disable_adds.sh` produces the same message as above.

It seems worth noting that the output field sometimes doesn't show anything even with just echo and that more than one command also doesn't seem to work

I have no idea how to proceed now to find out why the router doesn't acknowledge the existance of the script and how to get it to run.

Edit: I guess I should mention that I already tried following the troubleshooting steps at the end of the mentioned tutorial and that I'm trying to get it to work from a pc with windows 7.

Edit2: I formatted the text a bit as was suggested in the comments and added some more information. I hope it is more readable now.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Common mistake some members make is formatting. Many people will not read a huge bock of difficult to read text. Taking a minute to review [formatting](http://superuser.com/help/formatting), then [edit] your question to make it easier to read will increase your chances of getting the help you seek.

Comment: `/jffs/dns/` is not the same as `../jffs/dns`

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that you've not specified the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) properly.

When you run a script, this will tell the system how to execute it, try the following examples:

Trying to use `/bin/bat` as the interpreter (`/bin/bat` doesn't exist):

```bsh
$ cat <<EOF >test.sh
> #!/bin/bat
> hello
> EOF
$ chmod +x test.sh
$ ./test.sh
-bash: ./test.sh: /bin/bat: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Trying to use `/bin/cat` as the interpreter:

```bsh
$ cat <<EOF >test.sh
> #!/bin/cat
> hello
> EOF
$ chmod +x test.sh
$ ./test.sh
#!/bin/cat
hello
```

It's very possible that on a cutdown / embedded system, you'll be presented with the `not found` error you see above.

Check that you've typed that important first line correctly (`#!...`), and that the file listed there exists, and can be executed without error.

You will typically want something like `#!/bin/sh` (as specified in their `disable_adds.sh`).

**Edit:** It's also possible that you have a problem with line endings - make sure that WinSCP or whatever you're using to transfer the files doesn't play with them. [WinSCP FAQ](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_line_breaks).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I documented my solution here on my blog, http://studioforge.xyz/how-to-configure-cisco-linksys-wrt54g-v-2-to-run-pixelserv-on-dd-wrt/, it came down to running dos2unix on one of the files and re-uploading.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please [edit] your post to include the essential elements of the linked material. Good answers include specific instructions ([not just links to them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259)) and an explanation as to how/why the answer addresses the OPs question.